Does existentialism commit to some version of empiricism?
In asking this question, I necessarily parody the position of the Existentialists by reducing their position to the useful, but often times reductive, formula of: "Existence precedes essence". To me, this means that we are all, ultimately and radically, clean slates. That we are completely free to do whichever we like — we are unburdened and uncommitted to any character, position, or personality. The fact that we exist precedes the essence that was instilled within us.
Reading upon the Empiricism vs Rationalism debate on the SEP, I've come across the following thesis: "The Innate Knowledge Thesis: We have knowledge of some truths in a particular subject area, S, as part of our nature". In some way, some of our knowledge has been "a part of us all along". This marries existence and essence. Our knowledge being a part of our essence is interlocked with our existence — we cannot escape it, it is written in the very fabric of our being.
To me, this means that this thesis is incompatible with Existentialism. Reading the article further on, it ostensibly places the empiricists and the existentialists in the same bucket by asserting that "Empiricists reject this [Innate Knowledge Thesis]".
So my question is the following: Is this simply a happy accident? Or is it the case that all existentialists are somehow committed to, at the very least, a weak version of empiricism?

"I parody the position by reducing it to a formula" is generally a bad start when discussing a position. In this case, the formula is not even a "reduction", it has nothing to do with what it is taken to mean. Existentialism is concerned with ethics and coping with the world, not with epistemology, and "existence precedes essence" is not about innate knowledge at all. We can take ourselves to be "free or unburdened" to act regardless of what we know, innately or otherwise.

Not sure why andrós is being mean — I'm asking this question in good faith. To @Conifold, many ethical positions subsume some epistemological position: me doing so is not at all some random musing. Utilitarianism assumes some empiricism, and Kantian Ethics assumes some rationalism. To act upon something, you must know it, or have decided why to do it — which is its own special type of knowing. The point at the beginning is to explain my own shortcomings with existentialism. But I very much doubt I've explained their position, generally, as erroneously as you claim.

I don't see any problem incorporating some innate knowledge (such as how to breathe) in Heidegger's existentialism.  Innate, instinctive knowledge would be part of Dasein's facticity:

Whenever Dasein is, it is as a Fact; and the factuality of such a
Fact is what we shall call Dasein's "facticity". GA2
56


This characteristic of Dasein's Being—this 'that it is'—is veiled in
its "whence" and "whither", yet disclosed in itself all the more
unveiledly ; we call it the "thrownness" of this entity into its
"there"; indeed, it is thrown in such a way that, as
Being-in-the-world, it is the "there". The expression "thrownness" is
meant to suggest the facticity of its being delivered over. GA2
135

Also, Dasein's essence is its existence.

The 'essence' ["Wesen"] of this entity [Dasein] lies in its "to be"
[Zu-sein]. Its Being-what-it-is [Was-sein] (essentia) must, so far
as we can speak of it at all, be conceived in terms of its Being
(existentia) ...
The essence of Dasein lies in its existence. GA2 42

It seems the OP's confusion arises from equating Dasein's existence (Existenz) with 'clean slate', whereas the Being of Dasein arrives "thrown" in, albeit with an openness to the world.

Existentialism focusses on the innate property of each of us being first person agents, who are the only responsible parties for what we do, and the primary beneficiaries of our choices for good or ill.
This is a starting point for empiricism.  Most scientific empiricism tries to obscure the first person and agent features of we humans, and generalize as much as possible to the 3rd person and neutrality to the individual -- so there is a pretty rapid divergence from a similar starting point with empiricism.
Most philosophies have the ability to handle some degree of complexity.  Existentialism emphasizes and champions libertarian moral freedom, but most existentialists will admit that humans have predilections too.  And predilections translate to "intrinsic essence".  Existentialists note that we can always transcend these predilections. Are predilections "innate knowledge"?  Sort of.  I think inclinations can be mapped to your question, and have existentialists answering "yes we have innate knowledge of a form" but they would not agree it to be certain or necessarily accurate knowledge.  Existentialists and empiricists would share a rejection of certainty to have knowledge.
